# .sendSignedTransaction() Not sending Tx

Tags: javascript, transactions, ethereum, web3js

Bit of context; this was working fine on Goerli just a few days a go but the script now works intermittently. At the moment im thinking its down to one of the following:

1. Node issue - currently using infura and have tried changing it across other public RPCS but didn't work any better
2. Web3 issue - not sure if something is now outdated
3. Nonce issue with wallets, not sure if there is something obvious in the code here that is causing my Txs to get stuck and as such never return a receipt

For some reason this was all working fine last night after having not worked all day. Bit stuck as to what i could be doing wrong tbh. The logic is that based on a mempool tx, the sendTx function is invoked with the 'targetAddress' param which contains all the necessary objects to replicate the tx which i am tracking.

Tx.js:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
process.removeAllListeners('warning');

require('dotenv').config();

const INFURA_URL_TESTNET = process.env.INFURA_URL_TESTNET;

const web3 = new Web3(INFURA_URL_TESTNET);
const BN = web3.utils.BN;

// Tx details:

const sendTx = async (targetAddress) => {

    const address = targetAddress.address;
    const ethAmmount = targetAddress.value;
    const data = targetAddress.input;
    const gasLimit = targetAddress.gas;
    //const gasPrice = targetAddress.gasPrice - web3.utils.toWei('1', 'gwei');
    const maxFeePerGas = targetAddress.maxFeePerGas //- 1000000;
    const maxPriorityFeePerGas = targetAddress.maxPriorityFeePerGas //- 1000000;
    const privKey = targetAddress.privKey;
    const from = targetAddress.from;


    const _txCount = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(from);
  
    const createTransaction = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(
      { to: address,
        from: from,
        data: data,
        gas: gasLimit,
        value: ethAmmount,
        nonce: _txCount,
        maxFeePerGas: maxFeePerGas,
        maxPriorityFeePerGas: maxPriorityFeePerGas,
      },
      privKey,
    );
  
    // Send Tx and Wait for Receipt
    const createReceipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(createTransaction.rawTransaction);
    //const transaction = await web3.eth.getTransaction(createReceipt.transactionHash);

    console.log(`Tx successful with hash: ${createReceipt.transactionHash}`);
  };


module.exports = {sendTx};
```

The code stops at the await .sendSignedTx and doesn't return a receipt. As i said, this **does** work exactly as expected sometimes and i can figure out why sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using web3js, you have to handle the event promise chain when calling sendSignedTransaction and log all the payloads. That will tell you the reason for it not being broadcast. Could be a network error, gas issue, maybe nonce .e.t.c.

See https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/callbacks-promises-events.html#callbacks-promises-events